Google Maps API (Cloud Platform) How to change this text color using style editor (instead of JSON Array)?

When I changed the text fill color and stroke color it appears all fine on the preview Custom Maps editor, but when I applied the custom style to map-ID, and use the map-ID in javascript, the text color are not consistent; the POI has the expected color, but its business nature / type /or review rating has all different colors (as below)

At the moment I could only change their colors by using JSON array (instead of applying map styles to map-ID). Is there anyway to makes all text descriptions the same color?

The cloud editor is still quite buggy as far as I can tell. You should file a bug in the issue tracker or search for an existing one and star it.

Thanks for telling me that. I should have used JSON and get the job done easily but JSON method will be depreciated in 2025. :(  I will have a look at issue tracker. Many thx.

There is an existing bug filed regarding this issue where styling wouldn't be applied to secondary POI labels: https://issuetracker.google.com/357905821. In the meantime, to achieve consistent styling for POI labels, consider using vector-based maps as a workaround.
